# Matching a pattern that can be repeated in Regex

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression so that I can enter either one address like this C4:C15 or multiple ones (at most 3 in total) seperated by a comma like `B3:B5,B7:B10,C4:C6`

I already know how to enter each one separately using

```
^([B-" + Chr(Asc("A") + 2) + "])([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])?\:?\1([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])?(\,)?$
```

however how can I do that to add one or two more knowing that I know how many addresses I need but I don't want to do it in a for loop.

Comment: You would normally do this using the `*` quantifier. But the `\1` backreference causes a problem, because each repetition will refer back to the same original match, not the match in its own group. I'm not sure how to resolve this just with a regular expression. I think you may need to do the check that the row letter before and after `:` is the same in the application language, not the regexp.

Comment: will it be enogh? `^(?:([B-" + Chr(Asc("A") + 2) + "])([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])?\:?\1([2-9]|[1-9][0-9])?(\,)?){3}$` ? supposing that you want to repeat 3 times